# Why branch deleted in github still showing up in local?

Tags: git, github

I am not able to get when we delete a branch after merging in Github. Why does it still present in our local machine as remote/origin/:branch_name after git pull? Is it a bug or there is a specific reason behind this.

Comment: No, actually I want to know the logic behind this.

Comment: @KevinMartin Suppose you and I clone the same repository. I then remove the branch in github repository. Wouldn't it be scary for you that the branch in your local repository is gone without your knowing or approving?

Comment: The logic is quite nicely explained in the answer of the duplicate.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for helping me to understand this @jessehouwing.